# Unable to get values from JSON Array and Object

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, json

In my Javascript and PHP, I've manage to do an .ajax call to get an array. However when I want to display the display the values of each object I'm unable to do so.

PHP:

```
$request =  '{"request_id":' .$requestId. ', "reqName":"' .$requestName. '", "reqSubject":' .json_encode($requestSubjects). '}';

array_push($requestArray, $request);

echo json_encode($requestArray);
```

Javascript:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: serverURL + "getTutorRequestsProcess.php",
    data: sendTutId,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
        localStorage.setItem('pending', JSON.stringify(data));

        pending = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('pending'));
        console.log(pending);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert('Unable to retrieve requests.', null, 'Error','Done');
    }
});
```

So when I `console.log(pending)` it looks like this:

```
["{"request_id":13, "reqName":"Rin", "reqSubject":["English","A Math"]}", "{"request_id":14, "reqName":"Rin", "reqSubject":["English","E Math"]}"]
```

When I `console.log(pending[0])`, I'm able to get the first object:

```
{"request_id":13, "reqName":"Rin", "reqSubject":["English","A Math"]}
```

However when I want to get the values of the object like so, `console.log(pending[0].request_id)`, it returns an `undefined`.

Would highly appreciate if someone could tell me what's wrong with my codes. Thank you.

EDIT: I'm trying to add the data into my localStorage. Updated codes to reflect what I'm doing.

Updated Javascript:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: serverURL + "getTutorRequestsProcess.php",
    data: sendTutId,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
        localStorage.setItem('pending', JSON.stringify(data));

        pending = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('pending'));
        console.log(pending[0]);

        var response = jQuery.parseJSON(pending[i]);
        console.log(response.request_id);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert('Unable to retrieve requests.', null, 'Error','Done');
    }
})
```

**Both answers by OVM and Codeseeker works and solved my question. It's sad that I can't mark both as correct since both of them have provided two different but valid solutions.**

Comment: @dsg Tried that and it still returns an undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.` is used for to access object property while `[]` notation is used for to access array value.

```
console.log(data[0]['request_id']);
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8ek7moru/)**

Update:

Try with -

```
var response = jQuery.parseJSON(data0)
console.log(response.request_id);
```

Comment: Tried that but it still returns an undefined... :<

Comment: Thanks! It works. However, do you mind checking my updated Javascript and see if it's correct?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that you are serializing strings with json_encode, not real PHP classes and properties.

This resulting json is an array of strings and not an array of objects:

```
["{"request_id":13, "reqName":"Rin", "reqSubject":["English","A Math"]}", "{"request_id":14, "reqName":"Rin", "reqSubject":["English","E Math"]}"]
```

You want a result like this

```
[{"request_id":13, "reqName":"Rin", "reqSubject":["English","A Math"]}, {"request_id":14, "reqName":"Rin", "reqSubject":["English","E Math"]}]
```

To achieve that, try to build up a standard PHP object with those properties and serialize it. Don't serialize a string that contains json.

So on the server side, replace your first line of code with this and you'd be good to go:

```
$request = (object)['request_id': $requestId, 'reqName': $requestName, 'reqSubject': ['English', 'A Math']];
```

Comment: I'm quite new doing this, do you mind elaborating or show with examples?

Comment: In your first line of php code, you are creating a string, not an object. That string is serialized as a string, and not json. You would want to work with PHP objects on the php side and not with json strings. Thats why I showed you an example of how to build the object `(object)['request_id': $requestId, 'reqName': $requestName, 'reqSubject': ['English', 'A Math']];` Codeseekers Answer is correct, but basically just a workaround for your current inconsistent serialization mechanism.

Comment: Long story short: the `data` you are receiving in your ajax handler is an array of strings, and not an array of `JSON` objects. Therefore you need an additional `parseJSON` on each of the array items.

Comment: Alright. I understand. Thank you for the elaboration. I will try your method as well.

Comment: I did your method and I guess it feels more neater? Haha, thank you for helping!